# How can i get the last affected table in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the last affected table name (after insert).

I tried with `mysql_insert_id()` but i got only `id`.
I want table name also.

Can anyone give me the idea for my problem

Comment: Quite easy: When you do the `INSERT`, remember the table name ;-)

Comment: Your last insert statement could have affected multiple tables. So I don't think it's possible. **edit** : hold on. I'm doubting now. I don't think you can insert into multiple tables :s. You can update multiple tables though. So who knows.. Maybe it's possible.

Comment: You can't insert into multiple tables in one single **query**. However, you can use **transactions** to do it, or even **stored procedures**.

Comment: i have to do the changes in common function. so there is no way to find the table name there thats y i posted my question here

Comment: I dont want to insert multiple data. main thing is i want to table name which is affected recently(Insert)

Comment: or even triggers (although a trigger is a kind of stored procedures)!

Comment: @tsabz yes, but during the transaction you can have multiple last_insert_ids. So in regard to OP's question, I can't prove there is no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `mysql_query` function as defined in [this post](http://azgtech.wordpress.com/tag/override-mysql_query/), save you last call table name in global var or session and pray for last called insert finish last.

```
// THIS JUST SAMPLE... use code from link below ^
function custom_mysql_query($query){
    if(strstr('INSERT',$query)){
        /*GET YOUR TABLE NAME WITH REGEX*/
    }

    basic_mysql_query($query);
}
```

This is **very very very bad solution** for me. But in theory will work.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM random_table WHERE random_field LIKE "%INSERT%"` will break it

Comment: OP always can add few more checks in if. `... && !strstr('SELECT...`  and so on.

Comment: I tried this logic for SELECT and UPDATE but i want the logic for INSERT

Answer (score 1):

It's a strech... But if :

- you are running mysql 5.6.3 +
- you still have access to the insert query (let's say it's $query)
- you are sure it's an insert query (because, hey, you know you want last_insert_*, don't you?)

You can try:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("explain $query"));
$table = $row['table'];
```

From mysql 5.6.3+ you can combine `explain` with a `insert into` query.
This should return only 1 row, I think.
I dont have mysql 5.6.3+ myself to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in your comment that you're using a common function to apply the changes in, preventing you from 'knowing' what the last table is you inserted in.

If that's the case: **your logic is flawed**.

MySQL is not gonna tell you what the last table is it did an INSERT in. You will have to write a hook in your function where you last know what table you're gonna update. No matter what function you use, you **must** specifiy a table name at some point, before executing the insert. You store the table name at that point.

You can do that in many ways, depending on your needs:

1. store it in a mysql table (last_updated_table with only 1 column,
   for example)
2. store it in a variable (if you only need it in the
   same request)
3. store it in a session (I wouldn't opt for this)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `information_schema` database if you have one :

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, UPDATE_TIME 
FROM TABLES
ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC 
LIMIT 0,1
```

Use this after your query, and you'll get the affected table.

Comment: That's unreliable in his case.

Comment: This could return a different table of a different query that ran in a different thread. So I agree this is unreliable

Comment: Then you can't do it within MySQL itself. You have to adapt your logic into your PHP code to keep the table name in a variable or something.